# Alternate Definition of Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Looking at the "secant line $\to$ tangent line" motivation for the derivative I can't see any reason why one point on the graph of the function $f$ should be nailed down at the point in question.  Analytically, it's probably usually easier, but to me this alternate definition (which I think is equivalent) is more likely how I would have defined it:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}$$  Is this alternate definition ever used?  Would it ever be more useful than the standard definition?

---

EDIT: So this is a thing and it's called the symmetric derivative (thanks Ricky).  New question: can someone explain intuitively why this *isn't* equivalent to the usual definition of the derivative?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative $\;$

Comment: With this definition, $\lvert x\rvert $ has a derivative at $0$.

Comment: It says nothing about the value of f(x).In particular the symmetric derivative may exist at x without f being continuous at x.

Answer (score 2):

One reason is that
this is not defined
for functions defined on
a closed interval
at the endpoints of the interval.

Also,
as Bernard said,
it allows functions
to have a derivative
at points where
the usual derivative does not exists.

However,
where both definitions exist,
this is more accurate,
with an error of
$O(h^2)$
where the usual derivative
has an error of
$O(h)$.